# How to include an ES6 Promise when using the Aurelia-Webpack plugin?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, aurelia

I am using Aurelia 1.1 with the Webpack 2.0 plugin. This works fine in Chrome, but in IE, there is no promise.

So I get an error message on this:

```
var startPromise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
  return startResolve = resolve;
});
```

I have downloaded the es6 polyfill with npm, but I don't know how to tell webpack to include it so it can be used universally.

How should I be including this polyfill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual thing for ES6 apps is to have polyfills included (e.g. `core-js`). This should be done once per app, as early as possible, before other libraries:

```
import 'core-js/es6';
```

Considering that `aurelia-polyfills` is already used, polyfills can be included selectively to not collide with [the ones from `aurelia-polyfills`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-polyfills#polyfills-included):

```
import 'core-js/es6/promise';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
...
```

Comment: I installed core-js with npm, then added `import 'core-js/es6` to the top of main.js.  However, I still get the same error in IE.

Comment: This should work as expected. You can try `import 'core-js'` as well. See a plunk for example, http://plnkr.co/edit/VtZr7esRsb01bnUKXwG5?p=catalogue . It is IE11, isn't it?

Comment: I tested the plunk and it does work.  But it uses a script tag, instead of installing it with npm and then using an import statement.  That seems like a solution as well, but I was thinking there was a way to do this with webpack.  I looked in the webpack bundle of my test site and I do see the Promise code in there, but I think there needs to be something to initialize it.

Comment: import 'core-js' should definitely work, this is how it is usually done. It unconditionally polyfills window.Promise. You can also try require('core-js'), which is the same thing. There may be something wrong with your Webpack build.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is the best way, but it worked for me:

In webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

...

plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Promise: 'es6-promise-promise'
  })
```

]

Note that the "es6-promise-promise" [lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-promise) was installed.

More on [Plug-ins](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/):